# How to get size of installed apps on device using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using the [device_apps](https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps#-example-tab-) package to get names and other information of installed apps. But there is no option to get the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with device_apps library.

You can request this feature posting an issue on  https://github.com/g123k/flutter_plugin_device_apps/issues and wait an answer from contributors

Or

Create a pull request and implement this feature by yourself ;)